# Считывание Aztec кода на Android

Tags: java, android

Господа программисты, кто то сможет подсказать по считыванию штрих-кода?
Как в приложении Сбербанка сделали считывание квитанции по налогам?

Речь идет об Aztec коде на прикрепленном изображении. Сразу обозначу проблему:

1. Через Android Vision API (Barcode) - не считывает.
2. Через ZXing (самую популярную  open source библиотеку) - не считывает.

Нашел только 2 приложения в Google Play которые считывают:

1. Barcode Scanners
   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manateeworks.barcodescanners
2. NeoReader QR & Barcode Scanner
   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.gavitec.android
3. А так же официальное приложение Сбербанка

Как можно считать данные с представленного Aztec кода?

[image: Налоговая квитанция]
(источник: [migrantmedia.ru](https://migrantmedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/obrazec-kvitancii-na-oplatu-patenta-2016-obrazec-zapolneniya-kvitancii-na-oplatu-patenta.jpg))

Comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing заявлена поддержка Aztec (beta)

Comment: Может все дело в камере девайса? Android Vision API должен нормально работать.

Comment: barcode scanner от ZXing Team отлично понимает этот код

Comment: Тестирую на одном и том же устройстве - Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime. На других тоже пробовал, картина не меняется.
Библиотека от ZXing  не считывает привденный в примере код. Через Barcode Scanners и NeoReader QR & Barcode Scanner считывается код хорошо и сразу. Через пример приложения barcode-scanner от google с github не считывается.